# Get/Grep Property from plist Array

Tags: bash, macos, shell

Trying to get the last value from the "SnapshotDates" array, which itself is within an .plist array. Here's what I have so far, but it fails to provide more output than the first line.

```
defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine Destinations | egrep '.*SnapshotDates(.*\n)*'
```

Comment: Are you limited to Shell, or can you use a "Swift script" (which is much easier to read plist files)?

Comment: It will be used in an applescript, so either applescript or js as an alternative would be fine. But if you have a swift snippet ready, feel free to show it, might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To print the "SnapshotDates" array, use this Perl one liner, which prints all the dates:

```
defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine Destinations | \
  perl -0077 -ne 'print "$_\n" for m{SnapshotDates \s+ = \s+ [(] .*? \n ( [^)]* ) [)] }xms'
```

Output:

```
            "2018-06-07 19:52:01 +0000",
            "2018-06-07 20:30:46 +0000",
            "2018-06-07 21:31:40 +0000",
            "2018-06-07 22:48:26 +0000"
```

To print just the last snapshot date:

```
defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine Destinations | \
  perl -0077 -ne 'print "$_\n" for m{SnapshotDates \s+ = \s+ [(] [^)]* \n .*? "([^\n"]+)" \n \N* [)] }xms'
```

Output:

```
2018-06-07 22:48:26 +0000
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-00777` : Slurp files whole.

The regex uses these modifiers:
`/x` : Disregard whitespace and comments, for readability.
`/m` : Allow multiline matches.
`/s` : Allow `.` to match a newline (for maintainability, not really needed here).

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Comment: Thank you Timur for your very detailed & well formated answer ! Really appreciate it :) The first command works fine, but the one for printing only the last snapshot doesn't work for me for some reason.